# How to disable total_cell_count - in Cube OLAP

Tags: cube, olap-cube

A dictionary with keys:
 - total_cell_count - number of total cells in drilldown (after limit, before pagination). This value might not be present if it is disabled for computation on the server side.

But i don't know how to disable on the server side.
Thank you!